# When an intent is fired to start a new activity, does the previous activity still use the heap memory on the Dalvik VM?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm working on an application which has about 4 to 5 HorizontalScrollViews. Out of these, 3 are completely loaded with images. To get this working I had to overcome java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, many times. Thanks to all the friends on stackoverflow. Now, my next activity is again going to be filled, completely, with images. Therefore, I wanted to know whether heap is freed when a new activity begins?

Comment: If your Activity is in Background, Heap will be freed..

Comment: @sandy But will the images be downloaded again, in the previous activity, when i go back to it?

Comment: Cache the images to the External Storage, and then check to see if they are present when you load your activity. If they are, then pull the images from the External Storage, otherwise download them. You could add in another level and store the images in memory too (SoftReference) and pull from here before trying to pull from External Storage.

Answer (score 0):

If you will kill the previous activuty using **finish()** then it will not use heap memory else it will us else memory being in the background(stack).

Comment: but killing the activity will lead to loading all the images again, which could be time consuming and spoil the user experience. I dont want to download the images again.

Comment: @HarshalKshatriya: you can save the images to a cache on the SD-card or the internal phone memory.

Comment: @HarshalKshatriya yes as Jave told you can take the help of cache.